# JS- Having issues instantiating a class in a unit test (using class to class interaction)

Tags: javascript, class

Having issues on how to approach this test suite. I am asked to instantiate the Beer class within a method in the Bartender class.

This is my beer class:

```
  constructor(newBeer) {
    this.brewer = newBeer.brewer;
    this.name = newBeer.name;
    this.type = newBeer.type;
    this.price = newBeer.price;
    this.volume = newBeer.volume;
    this.isFlat = false;
  }
}
```

I have to push an instance of Beer into the orders array in the Bartender class and I am not sure how to approach. Here's my code for the Bartender class:

```
class Bartender {
  constructor(name, hourlyWage){
    this.name = name;
    this.hourlyWage = hourlyWage;
    this.orders = [];
  }
  takeOrder(newOrder) {
    var newOrder = new Beer;
    this.orders.push(newOrder);
  }
}
```

I keep getting this error message on my npm test:

```
 1) Bartender
       should be able to take orders:
     AssertionError: expected 'Grand Teton Brewing' to be an instance of Beer
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/bartender-test.js:33:12)
      at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:464:21)
```

This is the bartender unit test I keep failing:

```
it('should be able to take orders', function() {
    var bartender = new Bartender("Chaz", 8.50);

    bartender.takeOrder("Grand Teton Brewing", "Bitch Creek", "Brown Ale", 7, 16);

    assert.instanceOf(bartender.orders[0], Beer);
    assert.equal(bartender.orders.length, 1);
    assert.equal(bartender.orders[0].brewer, 'Grand Teton Brewing');
    assert.equal(bartender.orders[0].name, 'Bitch Creek');
    assert.equal(bartender.orders[0].type, 'Brown Ale');
    assert.equal(bartender.orders[0].price, 7);
    assert.equal(bartender.orders[0].volume, 16);
  });
```

Lmk if anyone has any advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the takeOrder function takes only one arguement. So only the first arguement is being considered which is a string.

You have to either create a Beer instance and send to the function takeOrder like

```
bartender.takeOrder(new Beer("Grand Teton Brewing", "Bitch Creek", "Brown Ale", 7, 16));

  takeOrder(newOrder) {
    this.orders.push(newOrder);
  }
```

Or edit your takeOrder function to get mulitple inputs and call the constructor of Beer class inside takeOrder.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do. My constructor for the Beer class is newBeer, how would I pass that into the takeOrder function?